# check for a boolean in list of random values

Tags: python

Since `0 == False` how do you check for a boolean in a list like this:

```
a = [4, 5, 3, 0, 9, False]
```

Normally I'd go like this:

```
if False in a:
   return 'yes'
```

but the fact that in computer science  0 == False make this:

```
if False in [4, 5, 3, 0, 9]:
    return 'yes'
```

return yes as well. How do I check for boolean per-se in a list ?

Comment: `0 == False` is True. `0 is False` is False. `False is False` is True.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
def contains_false(array: list):
    for item in array:
        if isinstance(item, bool) and not item:
            return 'yes'

    return 'no'
```